# How do I recall a message in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I've seen recall requests at work before, so I know the server is set up to support this action.  We use Outlook 2003, but I can't seem to find the message recall function on any of the menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a guide on the Office support site: 
[How Message Recall works](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/how-message-recall-works-HA001091760.aspx)

From there:

> Do the following:
>
> 1. In Mail, in the Navigation Pane, click Sent Items.
> 2. Open the message you want to recall or replace.
> 3. On the Actions menu, click `Recall This Message`.
> 4. Click Delete unread copies and replace with a new message.
> 5. Click OK, and then type a new message and include the attachment.
> 6. Click Send.
>
>    NOTE   If you are sending the message to a large number of people, you may want to consider clearing the Tell me if recall succeeds or fails for each recipient check box.

Comment: That works.  You have to *open* the message first, or the recall option doesn't appear in the Action menu.  I just had it selected in the main Outlook window.  Thanks!